# Execute powershell script on a remote computer using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, botframework

I have created a Bot Application using Microsoft Bot Framework and want to achieve the following:

1. To execute a Powershell script on remote computers without any authentication
2. The powershell scripts will be hosted on Azure or on a Database (may be any)

I have done following till now:

1. Was able to execute Powershell scripts on remote computers manually
2. Was able to execute Powershell scripts locally using C# code

Below is my current code:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectioninfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectioninfo.ComputerName = "<remote computer hostname>";
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectioninfo); 
//runspace.Open();
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{ 
   var re = ps.AddScript("Get-Service"); 
   var results = re.Invoke(); 
}
```

Comment: Who are the owners of the remote computers? Are they fully within your control - Do you manage the security policies for them?

Comment: You can use [Invoke-Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) if the remote computer has [PSRemoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/Enable-PSRemoting) enabled.

Comment: Hi Dylan/ James, I am not the owner of remote computers. I will be creating an administrator with which the Bot can login into remote computers and do the administrative stuff. Invoke-Command works fine from the powershell windows and with the manual intervention. I am searching a way to do the automatic remoting stuff through C# code.

Comment: @zee do you happened to solve the issue now? I have exactly same situation with you. really need help on this...

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are missing the bind of your `PowerShell` instance to the runspace.

```
ps.Runspace = runspace;
```

Take a look to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/schlepticons/2012/03/23/powershell-automation-and-remoting-a-c-love-story/) for more details.

Alternatively, you can create a Pipeline (as explained [here](https://com2kid.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/remotely-executing-commands-in-powershell-using-c/)) using the runspace and invoke the commands.

```
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline("<COMMAND TO EXECUTE REMOTELY>");

var results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Comment: Are there any pro's/con's for using the Pipeline over the ps.addCommand way of execution?